# How to parse tensorflow model with C++ API

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to parse a pre-trained model of tensorflow. For example, I want to get the full list of operation nodes, including the names and dependency given a model.

So, first I searched Java API and apparently there's little APIs supported by Java interface. So I seek for C++ API, but failed to find the right APIs.

The reason I don't use python is that I need to do this on android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TensorFlow graph is stored as a GraphDef protocol buffer. You should be able to build a java version of this and use it to inspect the stored graph. This will have the lists of operations, and their dependencies, but will have the values of the weights.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I suppose "build a java version of this" means I can leverage the protocol library in Java (from Google) and thus read the model?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.